# Flutter: Deeplinking user is being navigated to the screen of the link

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I have tried to implement deep-linking in my Flutter application - a Post Sharing Application.

I have made a system to share the link of the post to other platforms like Whatsapp. And when the user clicks on the link, it opens my app; all Good So Far, but when the app has opened, the user isn't being directed to that post_view page with PostID.
Upon printing the value, it shows that my value is empty.

Please help me know, what I could be missing or what wrongs I am doing.